# Sorting Data gridview by clicking header in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting, gridview

Please help me to sort the data in a grid view by clicking header in asp.net. i have used linq for bind data to gridview. Please help me.

Comment: a small google on the title of the question will answer you. Google returned About 192,000 results in (0.29 seconds).. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily.

So lets say you have a GridView, to which you assign the datasource at the server side.

you can make use of `GridView_Sorting` event, some thing like given below:

firstly, save the current applied sort somewhere. because, you need to know, whether you have to sort ascending or descending. something like below.

```
public SortDirection CurrentSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection) ViewState["sortDirection"];                
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; } 
}
```

and then use this property inside the `sorting` event of the GridView:

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   if (CurrentSortDirection== SortDirection.Ascending)
   {
      CurrentSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
      var myDataSource = GetDataThroughLinq()
                         .OrderByDescending(s=>s.Id)
                         .ToList();
      GridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   else
   {
      CurrentSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
      var myDataSource = GetDataThroughLinq()
                         .OrderBy(s=>s.Id)
                         .ToList();
      GridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly choose a datasource for the gridview, its in gridview tasks just below the auto format, after selecting datasouce more option is provided it includes sorting, paging and selection too, and by clicking on every heading, you will get the data sorted according to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sorting.....

```
protected void RadgvData_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
        e.Canceled = true;
        GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
        expression.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
        if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != e.SortExpression)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
        }
        else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
        }

        tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
        RadgvData.Rebind();

    }
```